# can not access ip address in local browser

Tags: linux, centos, xampp, ip-address

I'm using **xampp** on centos. When I browse `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` it's working. But when I am trying `http://10.102.1.10/phpmyadmin` then it is not working.

Comment: What does `traceroute 10.102.1.10` do?

Comment: traceroute to 10.102.1.10 (10.102.1.10), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.102.1.10 (10.102.1.10)  0.041 ms  0.036 ms  0.014 ms

Comment: Then when you say "it's not working", what exactly happens? Does your browser say it can't reach the address or there is something wrong with the page _after_ it's loaded?

Comment: While trying to retrieve the URL: http://10.102.11.63/

The following error was encountered:

    Connection to 10.102.11.63 Failed 

The system returned:

    (110) Connection timed out

The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.

Comment: The xampp server is propably only listening on the loopback device and not on the extern network device. Take a look here http://serverfault.com/questions/402533/cant-connect-to-xampp-apache-server-from-lan-or-outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

`http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` instead of `http:// 10.102.1.10 /phpmyadmin`

Comment: I want to browse with ip address from remote pc also

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin it's working but I want to run http:// 10.102.1.10/phpmyadmin

Comment: perhaps you check iptables.

Comment: I have to bind it in php.ini and in browser has to be written ip address into bypass proxy text box. then that computer ip address will show on browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use
127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin for localhost/phpmyadmin

Have you the checked that the IP is correct by trying to traceroute 10.102.1.10?

Comment: Now I changed my ip address is 10.102.11.63  . traceroute 10.102.11.63 showing result                          traceroute to 10.102.11.63 (10.102.11.63), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.102.11.63 (10.102.11.63)  0.030 ms  0.008 ms  0.008 ms